# What are the chained things in the Tower of the Cursed?

Tags: diablo-iii

In the Tower of the Cursed in Diablo III there are what look like huge demons chained in the depths that you can see from the walkways.  What exactly are they?  Is there lore related to them?

This may be answered in game, but unfortunately I tend to skip through the dialog pretty quickly.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain but I think they are just demons.

Comment: "I didn't read / listen to the in-game dialogue, so I'm asking here instead?" ;-)

Comment: If I knew where/when it was mentioned, I'd go to that bit but there's so many little comments that pop up briefly in the chat log from your follower that I don't even notice they've been said (I play on mute because we have a baby to avoid disturbing).

Answer (score 3):

They're kept prisoner by the demons. They tear large strips of flesh off of them and use the flesh to make the floors out of. They're called "flayer demons". Cydaea and your follower tell you about that.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the Cydaea monologues which refer to the demons in which Lukas Warsitz and you are referring to (She says a lot of stuff during this).

"These poor things live in eternal torment... I feast on their agony, their eternal anguish... The chains tear at their flesh... Hear their screams, such sweet music..."

And as per what Lukas said, these are what make you have to run in circles for so long.